# How to run SSIS pack immediately?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, etl

I'm trying to desgin a program, that 100 people need to input infornamtion of  300 projects in  Relational database(SQL SERVER), and then run SSIS pack to ETL and return calculation results from SSAS. Is it possible that I can pass varible of projet name individually to SSIS pack, and run SSIS pack on demand(not sql server agent scheduled way), so that I can get the SSAS results immediately for certain project? Is there any reference I can learn? 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you actually doing anything with SSIS or are you just using it as a means to have SSAS process the cube? Could you expand on what you are doing and how you envision SSIS will play a role in it? Click the edit button above amend your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What SQL Server version do you have? If 2012 and newer you can use SSIS Project Deployment Model and  Parameters and run packages using stored procedures = on demand

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj820152.aspx) you have information about run packages using stored procedures

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/hh213214%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) you have information about ssis parameters